# I have the exact same question, but in a different (programming) language

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I have this exact same question:

*[How to start a new process without administrator privileges from a process with administrator privileges?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169431/how-to-start-a-new-process-without-administrator-privileges-from-a-process-with)*

But for PowerShell. (I want an administrator PowerShell process to spawn a non-administrator process.)

How would I find the equivalent question for the PowerShell language? Is there some sort of linking system?

Comment: If it's in an entirely different programming language, it's not *exactly* the same question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is no existing system that "links" similar questions across multiple languages. Sometimes there would be cross-linking comments left by people on similar quests but that's pretty much it.

It is fine to ask new question in such case - you definitely need to show that you've already found solutions in other languages/frameworks (e.g. by linking to them from new question) and specify what exactly blocks you from conversion.

Note that in this particular case it is very unlikely to get any simpler solution due to nature of the problem.